# Squirrel SQL gives: FATAL: database "localhost:5432:postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I want to use Squirrel SQL since it seems a good alternative to pgAdmin but I do not succeed to connect with database postgresSQL, respectively, MariaDB. The error I got is:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "localhost:5432:postgres" does not exist

I have the following environment: Windows 7, postgreSQL 9.6, MariaDB 10.2. I can connect both databases with terminal or pgAdmin, respectively, HeidiSQL. So, I think I do something fundamentally wrong when trying to connect to the databases with Squirrel SQL.

Here are the detailled steps I did:

(1) The drivers are in C:\Program2\db_drivers and also the databases are installed in directory \Program2:
[image]

(2) I could register the drivers:

[image]

(3) Then I tried to make an alias:
[image]

(4) ... but got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) the URL should be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. MariaDB had also a very strange default entry: _jdbc:mysql:host:3306_ which I changed to _jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/_. Now it works.